# What version of SQL Server Express is this .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

I had SQL Server Express 2008, 2008 R2, and 2012 RC0 installed when I created an `.mdf` file. Now I cannot open it in 2008 R2. How can I check which version the file is, if I don't have 2012 RC0 installed anymore?

I removed all SQL Server versions from the computer and reinstalled 2008 R2. Looking through other posts, I see that I probably should have "detached" the database file first, but I did not know that at the time.

Comment: If you cannot open it in the 2008 R2 version, it's most like a 2012 RC0 file....

Comment: Thank you marc_s, but now that I've reinstalled 2012RC0 won't open it either, nor the backup file. Both were working fine before I removed the programs.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I am having a genuine issue that I cannot solve with casual googling that may affect others in the future as well.

Comment: I meant that the `connection.Open()` statement fails. I have updated the connection string with the proper `Data Source` for the running `2012 RC0` instance.

Comment: Hi Marc. It turns out that `2012 RC0` was intermittently shutting down. I noticed this by keeping the SQL Server Configuration Manager open while running my application. Removing `2012` and reinstalling then restarting the virtual machine fixed this. That is what I get for using a Release Candidate! Unfortunately they are [currently not accepting bugs](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-bugs), so when I reinstalled I checked the box to send usage information to Microsoft. Thank you for your patience, Marc.

Comment: check my blog on how to determine the version of mdf file
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/02/20/mapping-sql-mdf-file-versions-to-sql-product-versions.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to determine the database version of an MDF file](http://rusanu.com/2011/04/04/how-to-determine-the-database-version-of-an-mdf-file/):

> the version of the MDF will be the DWORD value at offset 0×12064 in
>   the file.

Answer (score 1):

Files are not versiones by express or not - only by file version / sql server version.

All the ones you name are downward compatible (2001 R2 opens a 2008 file and updates it). At the end thus.... it has to be 2012 RC0 if it is not able to be opened with 2008 R2. Simple logical elimination, no file check needed.

Comment: Thanks TomTom, but I was hoping to avoid the need to install `2012 RC0` if possible. In any case, now that I have reinstalled it, the file won't open in `2012 RC0` either.